# Creating radio button with text field in install4j

Tags: install4j

I want to create a form component that contains radio button along with text field for each of the radio button options. The radio button group component in install4j creates a radio button, however there is no option to create a text field along with it. Basically, I want to give an option to the user to allow him to enter either of the 2 values. Is there any other alternative? The value will be entered by the user and hence cannot use combo box. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "Single radio button" form component and "Text field" form component and put them into a "Horizontal group".

In the configuration of the "Single radio button" form component, select the "Coupled form component" tabs and select the text field form component. Then the text field will only be enabled is the radio button is selected.

Then, repeat this for each value of the radio button group and make sure that all "Single radio button" form components have the same value in their "Variable name" properties.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Horizontal/Vertical groups are introduced in which version of Install4j? Currently I'm using 4.2.5 and I don't seem to find it here. Might be in version 5.0?

Comment: Yes, it was added in 5.0.

Comment: Thanks! Will try and upgrade to 5.0.

Comment: I added horizontal groups as you suggested and was able to create a radio button along with a text field. I have 2 such horizontal groups each having a single radio button and a text field. How do I get the 2  text boxes which are contained in horizontal group ( 1 in each horizontal group) to be aligned vertically? Right now, the text boxes are not aligned.

Comment: It's not possible to specify this constraint. You could adjust the "Insets" properties of the text boxes to achieve alignment, but it's not cross-platform and depends on font sizes. Another possibility is to use a horizontal group at the top with two vertical groups inside, one for the radio buttons and one for the text fields. That solves the alignment of the text fields, but you still may have to adjust the inset properties for the vertical alignment.